# less css, define empty string variable

Tags: css, compilation, less

I want to define a variable, which could be empty in some cases
`@prefix: "";`

and to use it like this
`src: url("@{prefix}/path/to/something");`

the problem is that it compiles into
`src: url("""/path/to/something");`

How to define an empty string variable, that can be compiled in
`src: url("/path/to/something");`

**Update:**
Issue closed
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/532

Answer (score 18):

Just found a way to do this... escape an empty string  `@prefix: ~'';`

I ran into this with the box-shadow `inset` option that will often remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible in less. You could make a mixin function which returns the path with the prefix prepended to it. This would be useful if you want to change the prefix once in awhile and only have to do it in one place.

```
.prefixRed(@path: @defaultpath) {
    background: transparent url("red/@{path}");
}
.prefixBlue(@path: @defaultpath) {
    background: transparent url("blue/@{path}");
}
```